# Cannot find elements, but casper.exist shows true

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am facing a problem where my CasperJS cannot find specific elements even the selector is found.

Please refer to my code below :

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36');
casper.options.waitTimeout = 5000;
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1920, height: 1080};

casper.start('http://www.mega888.vip/login.html', function() {
    this.echo("Login Page Loaded.");
});

casper.waitForSelector('div.login-box-body', function() {
    if(!casper.exists('div.login-box-body')){
       this.echo("Login Box Body Exist");
    } else {
       this.echo("Login Box Body Not Exist");
    }

    if(!casper.exists('input#userName.form-control.input-lg')){
       this.echo("Username field Exist");
    } else {
       this.echo("Username field Not Exist");
    }

    if(!casper.exists('input#password.form-control.input-lg')){
       this.echo("Password field Exist");
    } else {
       this.echo("Password field Not Exist");
    }
});

casper.run();
```

From the code above, it echoes `Login Box Body Not Exist`, where it clearly already fulfill the condition `waitForSelector('div.login-box-body')`.

Furthermore, for `casper.exists('input#userName.form-control.input-lg` condition, it returns TRUE, but when I try to use `this.sendKeys` function, it says element cannot be found.

[image: Error 1]

Can anyone help me? I am getting nowhere with these code no matter how I try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the if statements inside a then() like this:

```
casper.then(function(){     
if(casper.exists('input#userName.form-control.input-lg')){
       this.echo("Username field Exist");
    } else {
       this.echo("Username field Not Exist");
    }
});
```

EDIT: remove the ! on the casper.exists(), so it will return `true` if exists and you want to show "Username Field Exists".